# The density of the distribution whose Laplace transform is the following

Tags: probability, laplace-transform

Is anybody aware of the density of the distribution whose Laplace transform is the following.

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \frac{e^{t/2}-1}{t/2}
\end{equation}

Note: $X$ is a continuous random variable, most probably bounded between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X \sim U([0,\frac 12])$, that is $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,\frac 12]$, we have
\begin{align*} \def\E{\mathbf E}
  \E[e^{tX}] &= 2\int_0^{\frac 12} \exp(tx)\, dx\\
             &= \frac 2t \exp(tx)\bigl|_0^{\frac 12}\\
             &= \frac{\exp(t/2) - 1}{t/2} 
\end{align*}
So the density with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbf R$ is $2\chi_{[0,\frac 12]}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a genius. I will ask a related question in a separate post. If you can answer that too, it will be great.

Comment: Sorry, I can post only once every 20 minutes. So, I will post later.